# leitura de arquivo com scanner

Tags: java, scanner

adoraria saber se alguém pode me ajudar com esse código abaixo, na minha aplicação o usuário com frequência irá subir alguns arquivos e eles tem duas informações, numero e nome separados por  -> ;
porem no arquivo eu simulo alguns possíveis problemas como números   sem nome e meu código não se comporta bem contra esses possíveis problemas.

Outro detalhe é que meu SOUT esta duplicando e eu não sei porque.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

```
    public void adicionaArquivo(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    List<ContatoDTO> contato = new ArrayList<>();

    //cria um scanner para ler o arquivo
    Scanner leitor = new Scanner(inputStream);
    //variavel que armazenara as linhas do arquivo
    String linhasDoArquivo = new String();

    //percorre todo o arquivo
    while (leitor.hasNext()) {

        try {
            //recebe cada linha do arquivo
            linhasDoArquivo = leitor.nextLine();

            //separa os campos entre as virgulas de cada linha
            String[] valoresEntreVirgulas = linhasDoArquivo.split(";");

            for (int i = 0; i < valoresEntreVirgulas.length; i++) {
                ContatoDTO c = new ContatoDTO();
                c.setTelefone(valoresEntreVirgulas[0]);
                c.setNome(valoresEntreVirgulas[1]);
                contato.add(c);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < contato.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("telefone : " + contato.get(i).getTelefone());
        System.out.println("Nome : " + contato.get(i).getNome());
    }
    System.out.println("qt de linhas : " + contato.size());
}
```

meu arquivo

```
71999998811;nome1
71999998812;nome2
71999998813;nome3
71999998814;nome4
71999998815;nome5
71999998816;nome6
71999998817;nome7
71999998818;nome8
71999998819;nome9
71999998810;nome10

71999998810;nome11
71999998810
71999998810;
71999998810;nome14
71999998855;nome15
```

meu log de erro q ficou grande

https://gist.github.com/fariasrod/d9d41e36856845327aa14110af5e3982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você tenta acessar um index que não necessariamente existe (nome). Dá pra fazer:

```
//separa os campos entre as virgulas de cada linha
String[] valoresEntreVirgulas = linhasDoArquivo.split(";");

ContatoDTO c = new ContatoDTO();
if(valoresEntreVirgulas.length > 0) {
    c.setTelefone(valoresEntreVirgulas[0]);
}
if(valoresEntreVirgulas.length > 1) {
    c.setNome(valoresEntreVirgulas[1]);
}
contato.add(c);
```

Ou usar regex:

```
public void adicionaArquivo(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\d]+)(?:;*)(.*)$");
    ....
    ....
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        ContatoDTO c = new ContatoDTO();
        if (matcher.groupCount() >= 1) {
          c.setTelefone(matcher.group(1));
        }

        if (matcher.groupCount() >= 2) {
          c.setNome(matcher.group(2));
        }
        contato.add(c);
    }
```